# IntelliJ IDEA - enable ligatures under Oracle JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Since last year, IntelliJ IDEA has the `enable ligatures` font option locked if running under Oracle JDK.
As with my 4K monitor OpenJDK looks bad, really bad, at font rendering, I'm forced using OracleJDK.

I'm running `2018.3.*`, latest EAP.

[image]

Is there a way to force IDEA enabling ligatures?

Comment: it tells you exactly what to do...

Comment: and oh, be prepared to pay Oracle handsomely for your JDK license.

Comment: @jwenting I cannot use their version of OpenJDK. I find a bit hideous locking options. Noone has to pay a penny to use OracleJDK

Comment: I have just created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37179

Comment: @Leonardo voted

Comment: @Leonardo you can see my "workaround" https://postimg.cc/4mJ4T13t
Anyway I don't recommend it

Comment: @LppEdd thanks! I don't know how to perform it, can you help?

Comment: @Leonardo sure! Let me compose a decent message. BTW, it's better if you remove your link that points to this bytecode editing thing in the Youtrack comment, I don't think it's legal

Comment: Opsie, sorry. Will remove.

Comment: @LppEdd any update? You should write as an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in the image in your question say to install a [JetBrains Runtime](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/JRE/JetBrains+Runtime).

The above page says this:

> JetBrains Runtime is a runtime environment for running IntelliJ Platform based products on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux. JetBrains Runtime is based on OpenJDK project with some modifications. These modifications include: Subpixel Anti-Aliasing, enhanced font rendering on Linux, HiDPI support, **ligatures**, some fixes for native crashes not presented in official builds, and other small enhancements.
>
> JetBrains Runtime is not a certified build of OpenJDK. Please, use at your own risk.

Basically ... stick with the ugly ligature-less text, or take the risk and use their recommended Java runtime.

Comment: Well that was obvious... I'll have to patch the Oracle JDK to result as "JetBrains" probably

Comment: Still, why LOCKING it?

Comment: Probably because they are fed up with people complaining about poor screen update performance after they have enabled ligatures with a standard Oracle / OpenJDK JRE.

Comment: Solved by editing the bytecode under SystemInfo.<clinit>. A bit dirty, but it works. https://i.postimg.cc/DyGSLjkC/Immagine.png